# EditText Always returning empty value

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am new in android. I'm trying to run a simple android code where I try to get value from a EditText field. But every time I am getting empty value. In this code I'm trying to get value of ID field and try to check whether it is empty or not and try to show it in a Toast message. but every time its returning empty.

***activity_main.xml***

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="87dp"
        android:text="Sign In"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textColorLink="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:text="ID"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:typeface="normal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Enter ID"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="Password"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="SignIn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"

        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

***MainActivity.java***

```
package task.com.helloworld;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    TextView textView;
    EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

        final String name = editText.getText().toString();
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               // textView.setText("Hello "+name+", Welcome to Android. ");
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(name))
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Edit Text is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Edit Text is not Empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

the value always returning as empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beacuse you are getting that edittext value in onCreate ...that value you have to get after onClicking on button. 
Try this..

```
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               // textView.setText("Hello "+name+", Welcome to Android. ");
             String name = editText.getText().toString();
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(name))
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Edit Text is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Edit Text is not Empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: String name = editText.getText().toString().trim();


you also use trim remove space

Answer (score 0):

In layout you haven't put any text. So it always return empty.
If you have any hard-coded text put in layout then it will return text.